# ¿Como mostrar en pantalla resultado con Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

Estoy tratando de traer un texto de una base de datos con mysqli y luego mostrarlo en pantalla.

este es mi codigo:

```
define('MISITIO', 'http://localhost/Practicas_de_PHP/Web-Personal/');

$datosWEB = "Cristian Garcia Web | Software and Web Developer.";

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "webpersonal");
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("Error en la conexion: " . $conexion->connect_erro);
}

$articulo = "SELECT texto FROM descripcion";

$resultado = $conexion->query($articulo);

if (!$articulo) {
    header('Location: https://google.com.ar/');
}
```

y en el main.php:

```
<?php
           while($textos = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
               return $textos;
           }
           ?>
           <p class="texto wow bounceInRight"><?php echo $textos; ?></p>
```

Mi problema es que no logo mostrar el texto en pantalla.

Comment: Bienvenido @badcash, te recomiendo hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que puedas saber más acerca de stackOverflow y ganes tu primera medalla, también entra aquí [ask] para que puedas realizar preguntas aceptas.

Comment: Es muy rara la forma en que tienes el código organizado: 1. Lanzas la consulta; 2. Preguntas si `$articulo` no es nulo, pero no lo será nunca, si observas lo que tienes en esa variable es la consulta, no un resultado de la misma; 3. Luego hablas algo de un `main` que no se sabe lo que es realmente ¿? 4. En el famoso `main` intentas leer los datos dentro de un `while` con un return (eso no tiene sentido) 5. Usas `fetch_assoc` ignorando lo que hace realmente ¿?  ¿De dónde te habrás guiado para escribir esto? ¿Qué es ese `main`?  ¿Por qué no lees los datos en el mismo sitio y los muestras?

Answer (score 0):

No estás declarando bien la variable para que puedas acceder al resultado de tu consulta, tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
<?php while($textos = $resultado->fetch_assoc()): ?>

<p class="texto wow bounceInRight"><?php echo $textos['texto']; ?></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Puedes consultar más acerca de esto aquí [mysqli-result.fetch-assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)
y para la [Sintaxis alternativa en estructuras de control](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php) aquí